# How to detect colors one at a time

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I need to detect two colors, one after one.
So this is an example of my program workflow:
detect and object with a specific color, after that object is close enough(specified how much) to the camera,
 the program should try to start looking for another color.

this what i tried so far

```py
# All python's imports

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
# Defining the two colors bound
blueLower = np.array([110, 50, 50])
blueUpper = np.array([130, 255, 255])

greenLower = np.array([29, 86, 6])
greenUpper = np.array([64, 255, 255])

# Defining a function to start the loop so i can later rerun it with different color bounds
def loop(lower, upper):

    while True:
    ....
    ....

# If the object is close enough, change the loopj arguments to search for a new color
    if radius > 250:
      loop(greenLower, greenUpper)
```

What happens, is when the radius is bigger than 250, it just reruns the original

Comment: Is this the exact code? It wouldn't search for a different colour each time if you explicitly send `greenLower` and `greenUpper` each time. You need to alternate `green` with `blue` in each function call.

Comment: this is the whole code, https://github.com/yassinebridi/ball-tracking/blob/master/detect_ball.py

Comment: "You need to alternate green with blue in each function call"
,
 How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `itertools` that is in the standard library (you do not need to install, just import). Although there are other ways you can toggle between values, this one is convenient. I changed some parts of you code, you can let me know if theres something you do not understand.

```
import itertools

blueLower = [110, 50, 50]
blueUpper = [130, 255, 255]

greenLower = [29, 86, 6]
greenUpper = [64, 255, 255]

greenBounds = (greenLower, greenUpper)
blueBounds = (blueLower, blueUpper)


def loop(colorBounds, iterator):
    radius = 0
    lower, upper = colorBounds
    print(lower, upper)
    while True:
        radius += 1
        if radius > 250:
            loop(iterator(), iterator)

toggle = itertools.cycle([greenBounds, blueBounds]).__next__
loop(greenBounds, toggle)
```

To clarify, I added `radius=0` and `radius += 1` for my own testing purposes.

Comment: This works exactly as intended now, i updated the code with corresponding changes.
 Thanks a lot @Ahmet